# Getting values from xml to .properties file in Java

Tags: java, xml, properties

I have db connection related properties in a .xml file. I want to use the same values in a .properties file. Is it possible to get values from .xml file and set to .properties?

--
Thanks

Exception while using **loadFromXML**

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid system identifier: http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
    at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:76)
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Properties.java:868)
    at com.generalsentiment.test.quartz.CronTriggerExample.run(CronTriggerExample.java:40)
    at com.generalsentiment.test.quartz.CronTriggerExample.main(CronTriggerExample.java:117)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid system identifier: http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
    at java.util.XMLUtils$Resolver.resolveEntity(XMLUtils.java:190)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.XMLUtils.getLoadingDoc(XMLUtils.java:102)
    at java.util.XMLUtils.load(XMLUtils.java:74)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

There will be an effort to create an XML property file with the values from your .properties file. The schema of your XML is not specified here; hence assuming it's not in the Java XML properties format.

Java XML property file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Hi</comment>
<entry key="foo">bar</entry>
<entry key="fu">baz</entry>
</properties>
```

Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LoadSampleXML {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis =
      new FileInputStream("sampleprops.xml");
    prop.loadFromXML(fis);
    prop.list(System.out);
    System.out.println("\nThe foo property: " +
        prop.getProperty("foo"));
  }
}
```

Sample code referred from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-tiger02254/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the javadocs for Properties. 
There is a [loadFromXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29) method that does exactly this.
The only restriction is that the XML file confirms a specific structure and should have the below `DOCTYPE` declaration as mentioned there.

`<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">`

Comment: It takes the values from a .xml file and add it to .properties file?

Comment: No it loads the properties from the XML into a Properties object. Once loaded you can get each property with getProperty("property name");

Comment: i am trying to do the same "loadFromXML" for  hibernate.cfg.xml file but its giving the exception. Added the exception details in the question

Comment: i am unable to add the line  <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">   to  the hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: @SangramAnand , it looks like you are confused on how xml works. Not all XML files are created the same - each one has it's own internal format as defined by the doctype.  The xml configuration for hibernate is not the same type of data as the loadFromXML is expecting. Putting the doctype into the file does not change the structure of the file.

IF you are familiar with databases, the doctype .dtd is the schema specification, where as the contents of the .xml is the actual data. Would it make sense to try to access arbitrary data using different schemas?

I hope that helps with your confusion.